# Know when user clicked cancel while using FB feed dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using fb [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) there used to be a way to tell when the user clicked cancel instead of post. I'm not receiving query strings like `?error_code=4201&error_message=User+canceled+the+Dialog+flow#_=_` any more.

How can I tell if the user clicked cancel so I know how to proceed with out asking permissions from the user

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: because they will input something to my site and they will click the feed button at the same time like "submit and share to fb". If they click cancel I would know that the user decided not to share it and that is important information.

Comment: And how to handle when user clicks cancel? Now the browser just hangs for me. When I click post it does the redirect.

Comment: why is that information important for you? that is a very important question to help you.

Comment: cannot set this as duplicate because there is no answer, but you should take a look at the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980676/detect-if-user-canceled-facebook-dialog-fb-ui-share-method